# Vertex and face Selection problem

Tags: mesh

Ever since I installed blender on my pc, only edges show orange in the edit mode, and the vertices and faces show no sign of selection. I tried installing other versions but never got any changes

Comment: Kindly watch blender tutorials. This is one of the most basic things to know about modelling in blender

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode, you can use the 1,2,3 keys on your keyboard to switch between vertex select mode, edge select mode, and face select mode in order. Or you could use these icons at the top to switch:[image]